# JAVA FX Button border difficulty

Tags: css, button, javafx

I have a button which has a small, propably 1px thick line at the bottom. I can't figure out how to remove it.
If you do click the button the line disappears, if you deselect it, the line appears again.

I´ve tried css commands like: border and background

[Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVOnz.png)

What command is capable of removing this line?

PS: The background of the button is an image which has the perfect size, I thought the picture may be to small and JAVA FX adds this white line, but even if I make the button smaller the line will stay.

Thank you!

CSS:

```
.text-shop-button {
    -fx-text-fill: white;
    -fx-background-image: url("../resources/Game/button.png");
    -fx-min-height: 40px;
    -fx-min-width: 120px;
    -fx-max-height: 40px;
    -fx-max-width: 120px;
    -fx-focus-color: transparent;
    -fx-faint-focus-color: transparent; 
    -fx-background-position: center;
}

.text-shop-button:pressed {
    -fx-min-height: 36px;
    -fx-min-width: 108px;
    -fx-max-height: 36px;
    -fx-max-width: 108px;
    -fx-font-size: 90%;
    -fx-background-position: center;
    -fx-background-size: 90%;
}
```

Comment: Can you edit the question and add the css that you use currently for styling the button?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a look at the help page on how to post a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You might also want to inspect your code with [Scenic View](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/) to figure out where the problem lies. Without more information in your question we cannot help you.

Comment: Sure :) Here you go!